# How to handle recurring short-lived tasks with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a setup with a webserver (NGINX) and a react-based frontend that uses webpack to build the final static sources.

The webserver has its own kubernetes `deployment` + `service`.

The frontend needs to be build before the webserver can serve the static html/js/css files - but after that, the `pod`/`container` can stop.

My idea was to share a `volume` between the webserver and the frontend `pod`. The frontend will write the generated files to the `volume` and the webserver can serve them from there. Whenever there is an update to the frontend sourcecode, the files need to be regenerated.

What is the best way to accomplish that using kubernetes tools?
Right now, I'm using a `init-container` to build - but this leads to a restart of the webserver `pod` as well, which wouldn't be neccessary.

Is this the best/only solution to this problem or should I use kubernetes' `jobs` for this kind of tasks?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. Here's how I think about this:

**Option 1: The static files represent built source code**

In this case, the static files that you want to serve should actually be packaged and built into the docker image of your nginx webserver (in the html directory say). When you want to update your frontend, you update the version of the image used and update the pod.

**Option 2: The static files represent state**

In this case, your approach is correct. Your 'state' (like a database) is stored in a folder. You then run an init container/job to initialise 'state' and then your webserver pod works fine.

I believe option 1 to be better for 2 reasons:

1. You can horizontally scale your webserver trivially by increasing the pod replica number. In option 2, you're actually dealing with state so that's a problem when you want to add more nodes to your underlying k8s cluster (you'll have to copy files/folders from one volume/folder to another).
2. The static files are actually the source code of your app. These are not uploaded media files or similar. In this case, it absolutely makes sense to make them a part of your docker image. Otherwise, it kind of defeats that advantage of containerising and deploying.

Comment: for option 2: init-container or job? what is the better tool? could I just create a job everytime the source changes?

Comment: init-container is useful only for the very first time you create a deployment. Since you want to keep a static server running, a job that modifies the particular volume is a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

**Jobs**, **Init** containers, or alternatively a **gitRepo** type of **Volume** would work for you.

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/volumes/#gitrepo

It is not clear in your question why you want to update the static content without simply re-deploying / updating the **Pod**.

Since somewhere, somehow, you have to build the webserver Docker image, it seems best to build the static content into the image: no moving parts once deployed, no need for volumes or storage. Overall it is simpler.

If you use any kind of automation tool for Docker builds, it's easy.
I personally use Jenkins to build Docker images based on a hook from git repo, and the image is simply rebuilt and deployed whenever the code changes.

Running a **Job** or **Init** container doesn't gain you much: sure the web server keeps running, but it's as easy to have a **Deployment** with rolling updates which will deploy the new **Pod** before the old one is torn down and you server will always be up too.

Keep it simple...

Comment: I don't want to rebuild the webserver container everytime the static content changes because the server is also proxying other requests to e.g. the API

Comment: K8s tries to ease that frequent update style deployment. You can issue a 0 downtime type deployment to your static server. So the old server and new server will co-exist. Then the old server will be retired. Just for your info, you should read this: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/#updating-a-deployment